# [No module named 'google.appengine' appengine local development error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-app-engine-python

I am migrating from python27 to python37. I have ported the python2 code to python3 code. The problem is when i try to run the development server, it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.appengine'`. I have the google cloud sdk downloaded.

I also have the following google libaries downloaded:

`google==2.03`; `google-api-core==1.17.0`; `google-auth==1.14.3`; `google-cloud==0.34.0`; `google-cloud-core==1.3.0`; `google-cloud-datastore==1.120`; `google-cloud-ndb==1.2.0`; `google-cloud-storage==1.28.0`;

I am using the CLOUD_DATASTORE. Does this have anything to do with that? Do i have to migrate?

Here is the full error:

```
INFO     2020-05-12 15:58:51,741 instance_factory.py:261] Running /tmp/tmpAvEFgc/bin/pip install -r /tmp/tmpjm7s5D

INFO     2020-05-12 15:59:02,605 dispatcher.py:267] Starting module "default" running at: http://192.168.1.15:8080
INFO     2020-05-12 15:59:02,613 instance_factory.py:121] Detected Python 3.7.5

INFO     2020-05-12 15:59:03,607 instance.py:561] Cannot decide GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT, using "test" as a fake value
[2020-05-12 11:59:03 -0400] [30089] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2020-05-12 11:59:03 -0400] [30089] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:21217 (30089)
[2020-05-12 11:59:03 -0400] [30089] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-05-12 11:59:03 -0400] [30092] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 30092
[2020-05-12 11:59:03 -0400] [30092] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmpAvEFgc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/tmp/tmpAvEFgc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/tmp/tmpAvEFgc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/tmp/tmpAvEFgc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/tmp/tmpAvEFgc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/tmp/tmpAvEFgc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/tmp/tmpAvEFgc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/vicktree/Documents/project-noah-3/noah-app/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    from handlers.noah_handler import NoahHandler
  File "/home/vicktree/Documents/project-noah-3/noah-app/handlers/noah_handler.py", line 16, in <module>
    from google.appengine.ext import db
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.appengine'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `google.appengine` module is baked into the first-generation Python (2.7) runtime. It's not available to install via `pip`, in the second-generation (3.7) runtime, or in any Docker environment.

The only way to use it is by writing and deploying a first-generation App Engine app.

Depending on what you're doing, you should be able to replace it with a client library call instead.

See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrate-to-python3 for more details.

Comment: hey Dustin, just a another quick question. So one of the imports is `from google.appengine.api import datastore`. I have to simply delete this and just use the datastore client library directly? Is this going to be alot of work? Also curious if you have any same code

Comment: @VickTree See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrate-to-python3/migrating-services#datastore